# Is there a quick way to add multiple constrains in Excel Solver Optimizer?

Tags: microsoft-excel, solver

I'm doing a simple constrained optimization on 16 variables and I already have 64 constraints. It's incredibly painful to add the constraints one by one using the add button.[image]

link to file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cPEprFzkM4hm9wvTiZ9CvzCAIihaiko6/view?usp=sharing

Cells D21 D22 and D23 indicate one set of constraints "Restablize". Namely that

$V$7 >= $V$3:$V$6,$V$10:$V$14 and
$V$8 >= $V$3:$V$6,$V$10:$V$14 and
$V$8 >= $V$3:$V$6,$V$10:$V$14

Is it possible somehow type the constraints in a text file and then upload it or any other trick?

[image: image2]

[image: image2]

Comment: Use ranges. `$V$10:$V$3 <= $V$4`, `$V$3 >= $V$7,$V$9,$V$10:$V$14` and so on...

Comment: When you use ranges in both sides of (un)equiation then: 1) The amount of cells in both ranges must be equal 2) Each range is linearized by subrange then by row then by column 3) Than the cells with the same number are checked.

Comment: Hi @Akina When I entered the ranges the way you mentioned in your first comment then it didn't work. Actually $v$1:$V$3 <= $V$4 worked but $V$4 >= $V$1:$V$3 didn't work. I don't understand your second comment. Can you please write it in the form of an equation? or explain more.

Comment: Two shown rules replaces 11 of 13 your constraints (except the first and the last ones). If you cannot then share the modelling file.

Comment: @Akina please see screenshots in the question. The comma stuff isn't working for me for some reason. umm.. ok let me share the file on google drive.

Comment: *The comma stuff isn't working for me for some reason.* Select the destination multi-range by the mouse pressing Ctrl key and look for proper multi-range syntax in your Excel version. Maybe the delimiter is a semicolon?